# String replacement when regex reverse group is null in java

Tags: java, regex

**I want to convert a software version number into a github tag name by regular expression.**

For example, the version of `ognl` is usually `3.2.1`. What I want is the tag name `OGNL_3_2_1`

So we can use `String::replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` method like this

```
"3.2.1".replaceAll("(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)", "OGNL_$1_$2_$3")
```

And we can get the tag name `OGNL_3_2_1` easily.

But when it comes to `3.2`, I want the regex still working so I change it into `(\d+).(\d+)(?:.(\d+))?`.

Execute the code again, what I get is `OGNL_3_2_` rather than `OGNL_3_2`. **The underline `_` at the tail is not what I want**. It is resulted by the null group for `$3`

So how can I write a suitable replacement to solve this case?

When the group for $3 is null, the underline `_` should disappear

Thanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the last `.` + digits part optional by enclosing it with an optional non-capturing group and use a lambda as a replacement argument with `Matcher.replaceAll` in the latest Java versions:

```java
String regex = "(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+))?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        
String s="3.2.1";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
String result = m.replaceAll(x ->
        x.group(3) != null ? "OGNL_" + x.group(1) + "_" + x.group(2) + "_" + x.group(3) :
              "OGNL_" + x.group(1) + "_" + x.group(2) );
System.out.println(result);
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/M7T3l3).

The `(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?` pattern (note that literal `.` are escaped) matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more digits, then matches a dot, then captures one or more digits into Group 2 and then optionally matches a dot and digits (captured into Group 3). If Group 3 is not `null`, add the `_` and Group 3 value, else, omit this part when building the final replacement value.

Comment: However, there are so many repositories and it's too tiring to write every lambda for tags of every repo. For example, 1.5.1, 1.5-rc1 and 1.5-beta-2 of dom4j corresponding to dom4j_1_5_1, dom4j_1_5_rc_1 and dom4j_1_5_beta_2 in dom4j repo, these are really troublesome to write this.

Comment: Maybe I can save the regex and the lambda for every repo. And parse the lambda for every repo by LambdaParser when needed.

Comment: @TalentS If you do not want to build various replacements dynamically use separate regex replacements then, each tailored for each type of the string input.